# pick and choose kwargs to send to functions

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, inspect

I'm writing test cases for a broad list of functions. They are generalized below:

```
def func_a(x, y, z):
    return x + y + z

def func_b(x, y):
    return x + y

def func_c(w, x, y, z):
    return w + x + y + z
```

As you can see, these functions all use a subset of the same kwarg list (w, x, y, z). I want to avoid writing unittests that individually specify the argument values to pass and generalize my solution. Is there a way for me to selectively pass only the required subset of kwargs into each function to test?

Seems like a common problem - and I'm asking before I dive into making use of `inspect.getargspec()`.

NOTE: Feel free to suggest new titles here.

Comment: I don't get what you are up to, maybe more concrete example would help. Why all functions are named the same?

Comment: oops that was a mistake in my example. the functions are all differently named

Comment: Still it's not clear what you really want to achieve, do you have a real example of that functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass an iterable into the function.

```
x = [1,2,3]
assert(func_a(*x) == sum(x))
```